# how to change axis values in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to change the values of axis...but just the axis text and not the graph.

For example, I have data as

```
x = [10,20,30,40]
y = [100,200,3000,400000]
```

Now,the graph is between x and y

so

```
plt.plot(x,y)
```

but in the axis I want

```
ax_x = [ex/10 for ex in x]
ax_y = [math.log(y) for ey in y]
```

And the axis of this graph has ax_x and ax_y as values instead of x and y?

How do i do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use `plot(x/10, np.log(y))`?

Answer (score 3):

```
plt.gca().set_xticks(x, minor=False)
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(ax_x)
plt.draw()
```

Similar for y axis

Comment: While this solves the problem it is _really_ bad practice.  Your data and your labels are now _completely_ de-coupled.